# how can I stop my site scrolling horizontaly and instead have it wrap onto a new line?

Tags: html, css, scroll

Thanks for solving this issue,
this might be a duplicate but I am new to this and am wondering how I can stop this horizontal scroll on my site, here is a link to it as a codepen [codepen](https://codepen.io/Person2356/pen/bGayoXe) and here is it on github [github](https://github.com/Person2356/website)
as i have mentioned I am struggling to get the horizontal scroll to stop and I would rather it wraps onto a new line rather than having it scroll onto a white space
here is an example of the issue[example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEvzc.png)
thanks
navbar code as this is causing issue

```
  <nav class="navbar">
<div class="logo">
  <a href=index.html>
    <img src="Addy Schroeders.png" width="60px" height="60px">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      Home
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      About
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      help and resources
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="services">
    <a href="/">
      pages
    </a>
    <!-- DROPDOWN MENU -->
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li>
        <a href="template.html">
          Dropdown 1
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">
          Dropdown 2
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">
          Dropdown 2
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">
          Dropdown 3
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">
          Dropdown 4
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      Contact
    </a>
  </li>
</div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap the content, you can use `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap`. This should make it wrap to a new line and fix your issue!

Comment: thanls but neither of these worked, unless I am adding them in the right place, where abouts in the css should they go?

Comment: Add both the elements to the menu class in css, that should do the trick when you resize the window.

Answer (score 1):

The [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) CSS property can help you set whether flex items are either one line, or if they can wrap in multiple lines.

Comment: It does in the same block as `displey: flex`